# The differentiation process is unstable with the $||f||_{\infty}=\text{max}_{0\leq x\leq 1}|f(x)|$, where $f\in C^1[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

**The differentiation process is unstable with the $||f||_{\infty}=\text{max}_{0\leq x\leq 1}|f(x)|$, where $f\in C^1[0,1]$.**

I know that the process of differentiating a function is not stable, so take for example $f(x)=1$ and $f_n(x)=1+\frac{1}{n}\sin(n^2x)$. Clearly $f_n\to f$ but $f_n'\nrightarrow f'$. My question is whether changing this normal By $||f||_{C^1[0,1]}=||f||_{\infty}+||f'||_{\infty}$ can we conclude that the differentiation process is stable or unstable? In my opinion it is unstable but I can not find a counterexample, could someone help me please? In the case that it is stable, how would it be tested? Thank you very much.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do exactly. It is certainly stable as a map of $C^1$ (with the norm you propose) into $C^0$ (with the sup norm). It is not stable (not even well defined) as a map of $C^1$ into $C^1$ with your proposed norm on both $C^1$ spaces.

Comment: @PhoemueX How can I prove this formally?

Comment: Just note $\|f' - g'\|_\infty \leq \|f-g\|_{C^1}$, which gives the stability (depending on your exact definition of stability, you might need to add one or two lines to fully prove this). For the second claim, consider $f_n(x) = n^{-3/2} e^{-n} \cdot e^{nx}, x \in [0,1]$. Then $\|f_n'\|_\infty \leq n^{-1/2} \to 0$ and $\|f_n\|_\infty \leq n^{-3/2} \to 0$, so that $\|f_n\|_{C^1} \to 0$, but $\|f_n'\|_{C^1} \geq \|f_n''\|_\infty \geq f_n ''(1) = n^{1/2} \to \infty$.